# Change jQuery video bxslider depending on current video duration

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I need to change (slide) jQuery video bxslider depending on current video duration. Please help me...

http://bxslider.com/v3
.
.
http://bxslider.com/examples/video

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  video: true,
  useCSS: false
});